# Unfair coin probability

Tags: probability

This question has me looking like an idiot in my stats class and I need help this is the problem.
I have an unfair coin that lands on tails 75% of the time, what is the probability that it dosnt land on tails until the 5th flip.

Comment: https://statisticsbyjim.com/probability/multiplication-rule-calculating-probabilities/

Comment: How would you solve it if it were asking about the second flip rather than the fifth?